# How to replace sum(count() over(partition by x))

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Trying to figure out how to do the following:
`sum(case when count(goal_id) over (partition by user_id) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as user_with_multiple_goals`. This is obviously not supported- but I would prefer to not add more subqueries if possible in any way..

Any suggestions?

Table:

```
user_id goal_id
A       A
A       B
A       C
B       D
C       E
C       F
```

Output:
`2`

Comment: Table structure?

Comment: one:many user_id/goal_id

Comment: Classic case of overthinking a problem, just `GROUP BY user_id` and check the `COUNT(goal_id)` for each group.

Comment: @haag1 need to sum count of goal_id for each group...

Comment: Well you keep changing your question, in the future please think it through first before changing the scope of it 3 times. Just throw the results from the query into a table variable and `SELECT SUM(goal_id) FROM @tableVariable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, this can be simplified to a normal case/count:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END as user_with_multiple_goals
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
```

**Post edit:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Sorry confused myself, please see revised output expectation. Your query gives the same as `case when count(goal_id) over (partition by user_id) > 0 then 1 else 0 end` without the wrapping of `sum()` around it

Comment: its fine ill just throw in my statement in an existing subquery and sum in the select

Comment: @user8834780 That's probably the cleanest way to do it.  I added an alternative, but it will get complicated if your real query is more complex

Comment: @user8834780 NP

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking:

```
select count(*)
from (select user_id, count(*) as num_goals
      from t
      group by user_id
     ) u
where num_goals > 1;
```

Or:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.goal_id <> t.goal_id);
```